# How to set serial port parameters with stty?

Tags: serial-port

I am working with a serial port (RS232), and i have come across the following.

When i list serial port settings with

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0
```

i get, among other things:

> ... eof = ^D; eol = ; eol2 =

How can i set end of line charater to the line feed? That is - i do not know where to get table of character representations (so that i could understand what all ^C mean) and how should it be entered in the following command:

```
sudo stty /dev/ttyS0 9600 eol=<line feed>
```

When i try to send or recieve character data from it with

```
echo 'hello' > /dev/ttyS0
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

all i get is blinking cursor, and no data seem to transmit.

Comment: From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) I understand that the standard line feed character is CTRL+J or ^J. You could try that.

Comment: It seems your answer is correct; please post it as such; although it seems that does not resolve my actual problem

Comment: Note...I have been collecting data from devices with RS232. Some devices have settings (mine has...Keithley) where you set which char do you want to be EOL.

Answer (score 0):

> From [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) I understand that the standard line feed character is
> CTRL+J or ^J. You could try that.

–
Jos

Just note, that while on setting you need to type <kbd>^</kbd> as it is, while on runtime you should use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> itself.